# VBA "INSERT INTO" error - Importing data from Excel

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm using a VBA code in excel to pick some data and insert it into an Access DB. I need this for several tables.

The problem is: For some of those tables, I get an error like: "INSERT INTO syntax error". But, if I get the string the code generates and uses for inserting, and use it in SQL mode form Access, the query works just fine. So that doesn't make any sense. Here is a piece of it:

```
For j = 6 To lastrow

            SQLStr = "INSERT INTO TENSILE(REFERENCE, REF_ID, POSITION, RATIO, YSL0, YSL90, YSL180, YSL270, YST0, YST90, YST180, YST270, UTSL0, UTSL90, UTSL180, UTSL270, UTST0, UTST90, UTST180, UTST270, EL0, EL90, EL180, EL270, ET0, ET90, ET180, ET270, ARL0, ARL90, ARL180, ARL270, ART0, ART90, ART180, ART270) SELECT '" & ws3.Cells(j, 1) & "', REF.ID,'" & ws3.Cells(j, 60).Value & "'"

            For i = 61 To 93

                SQLStr = SQLStr & "," & ws3.Cells(j, i).Value

            Next i

            SQLStr = SQLStr & " FROM REF WHERE REF.REFERENCE LIKE '" & ws3.Cells(j, 1) & "'"
            ws3.Cells(7, 3).Value = SQLStr
            MsgBox (SQLStr)
            'rs.Open SQLStr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic 'Opening the query


        Next j
```

it's important to notice that this same structure is used for other tables and works normaly, like in:

```
For j = 6 To lastrow

            SQLStr = "INSERT INTO METALOGRAPHY(REFERENCE, REF_ID,  AUSTGRAINSIZE) SELECT '" & ws3.Cells(j, 1) & "',REF.ID ," & ws3.Cells(j, 18).Value & " FROM REF WHERE REF.REFERENCE LIKE '" & ws3.Cells(j, 1) & "'"
            'MsgBox (SQLStr)
            'ws3.Cells(2, 3).Value = SQLStr
            rs.Open SQLStr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic 'Opening the query


        Next j
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please pose the exact SQL code which results in the error, or at the very least, your data which causes the code to generate a SQL query which errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing how you are linked to the Access DB so that you could use a statement like:

```
db.execute SQLStr
```

This should solve your problem